# how to reload page automatically after completion of the action of the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to auto-reload the page after completion of the action of the form.

The code for my form is:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" action="<%=(String)request.getAttribute("base_url")%>files/upload/">
```

Comment: Share some code and details. So we can help you.

Comment: Not enough information about this `form` does the form trigger any javascript functions? Does it post data to another page?

Comment: i just want to reload the page after the file is uploaded Jitendra Khatri ji

Comment: yes the form is posting data to other page as well

Comment: @BimalBhandari which server-side language are you using to upload the file? I don't feel like playing guessing games today. Please edit your question and display the relevant information starting with your choice of server-side language. *used to process the upload*

Comment: ya i m using java as my server-side language @NewToJS

Comment: @BimalBhandari I think it would be a good idea for you to tag `java` in your question, this will help others who read your post understand which server-side language you're using. Please don't confuse `java` with `javascript` if your question doesn't relate to javascript please remove the tag.  Thank you.

Comment: So you found no answer still? Or just didn't pick one..?

Answer (score 0):

The browser will load whatever URL you specify in the `action` attribute.

If you want to reload the previous page then your *server side* code should output an HTTP redirect back to the previous page.

```
Location: http://example.com/page/with/form/on/it/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Use the `header()` function.

To redirect to another page using this function, simply put in quotations

`'Location: $desired_file'`

- An example of a header function used to redirect to another page could be: `header('Location: example.php');`.

For further instruction/help please see this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

**EDIT:** If you are trying to send data to a page using the action attribute, you WILL be redirected to that page. I'd like to help more but your question is not very clear.